# Getting rid of capistrano password confirmation for mkdir command in vagrant environment

Tags: vagrant, capistrano

I'm using two identical vagrant boxes which are used for testing capistrano deployment process. I can successfully deploy application from `dev` box to `prod` box. However, I cannot get rid of password confirmation.

As far as I can see from output, the confirmation occurs when deployment process is trying to run `mkdir -p /capistrano/tmp` as show below.

```
$ bundle exec cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /capistrano/tmp
vagrant@192.168.99.50's password:
```

The current permissions on `prod` server as follows (I've granted 777 manually as described [scp: /tmp/git-ssh.sh: Permission denied](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/687)):

```
vagrant@prod:~$ ls -l /
drwxrwxrwx  3 vagrant vagrant  4096 Apr  7 16:30 capistrano

vagrant@prod:~$ ls -l /capistrano/
drwxrwxrwx 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Apr  7 16:33 tmp
```

Then when I type password, it creates `git-ssh-football-production-vagrant.sh` under `/capistrano/tmp/` path.

```
vagrant@prod:~$ ls -l /capistrano/tmp/
-rwx------ 1 vagrant vagrant 93 Apr  7 16:33 git-ssh-football-production-vagrant.sh
```

I've removed/created/used different folders with 777 permissions for vagrant user and tried `www-data` as well but couldn't get rid of the password confirmation.

**deploy.rb**

```
...
set :tmp_dir, "/capistrano/tmp"
set :user, "vagrant"
...
```

**production.rb**

```
role :app, %w{vagrant@192.168.99.50}
server '192.168.99.50', user: 'vagrant', roles: %w{app}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. All I had to do was to add `dev` server's public key to `prod` server's `authorized_keys` with command below.

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh vagrant@192.168.99.40 'cat >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```